# What is the comparative degree of the word "last"?

Tags: adjectives, degree-of-comparison

What is the comparative degree of "last"?

I have searched a lot on Google but have not been able to find the answer.

Comment: consider migrating this to ell?

Comment: Closely related: [**Late “latter” last**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/443733/late-latter-last)

Comment: I think that phrases such as *second last* and *third last* could function as comparatives in this case.

Comment: I see, it's you. Where did you find the explanation in [your answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/478495/44619)? P.S. You can post an answer to your own question, but please attribute it to the source.

Comment: _Last_ is already a superlative (notice the -st). So it doesn't have a comparative.

Comment: How about [penultimate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/penultimate)?

Answer (score 1):

"Last" is an adjective that has no comparative. superlative forms as last already has the meaning of the **most** bottom, behind, etc.

Comment: What about "latest"?

Comment: latest is the superlative of late, as far as i know

Comment: I'm nudging you to make your answer more complete....

Comment: I am bit confused whether it's positive and comparative are Late and Latter.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. _Last_ is a superlative that does have a corresponding comparative degree (_latter_) and also arguably a positive degree (_late_). There are very few superlatives in English that do not have corresponding comparatives (_first_, _utmost_, etc.).

Comment: yes, but its **late, latter, latest**. the OP is asking about "last", which i believe is another issue

Comment: and last is the same case as utmost and first, as far as i know

Comment: _Last_ is an old superlative. Now _late_ has regularized, and _last_ has changed its meaning to the end of a sequence. You can go in the other way -- _next-to-last_ -- but that's not comparative. The same thing happened to the old _nigh - near - next_, but now _nigh_ is archaic and _near_ has regularized into _near -nearer - nearest_. Happens all the time.

Comment: Is this your *very last* post on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

The comparative form of the superlative "last" is "latter". It is not to be confused with "later", the comparative of the positive adjective "late".
Arguably, the positive (that is, non-comparative, non-superlative) of "last" is the suppletive "one", which it shares with "first" and "former" in their shared role of list demarcation.